# Rubygems 2.7.3 setup error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macos-high-sierra

I'm incredibly new to Ruby, and that includes installing rubygems so I can learn to make my own gems. I cloned the repository properly and was able to update the bundler submodule just fine, but every time I go to run `ruby setup.rb` I get the following:

```
Ran-sin-MacBook-Pro:rubygems ran$ ruby setup.rb
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb
```

So naturally I tried with `sudo` and got this:

```
Ran-sin-MacBook-Pro:rubygems ran$ sudo ruby setup.rb
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/gem
```

Any ideas or fixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a permissions issue, to claim the ownership you can try

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Library`

if it didn't work, try this too

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Library/Ruby`

Don't use or avoid using `sudo`

Comment: You were right, and claiming ownership using ```sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Library``` worked wonders. Thanks!